# Drop database with reactive Mongo

Tags: mongodb, scala, reactivemongo

I need to drop a Mongo database using ReactiveMongo. Since ReactiveMongo does not provide specialiaed API for that I decided to use "runCommand" function.

This is how a database can be deleted in Mongo shell:

```
> db.runCommand("dropDatabase")
{ "dropped" : "123", "ok" : 1 }
```

But when I try to do the same with Reactive Mongo:

```
val runner = Command.run(BSONSerializationPack)
val dbDropDoc = BSONString("dropDatabase") 
val dbDropResult = runner.apply(db, runner.rawCommand(dbDropDoc)).one[BSONDocument]
```

I receive the following compilation error:

```
[error] ...: could not find implicit value for parameter writer: runner.pack.Writer[reactivemongo.bson.BSONString]
[error]     val dbDropResult = runner.apply(db, runner.rawCommand(dbDropDoc)).one[BSONDocument]
[error]
```

How should I fix my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is much more easy way to do so: [DefaultDB.drop()](http://reactivemongo.org/releases/0.11/api/index.html#reactivemongo.api.DefaultDB@drop()(implicitec:scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext):scala.concurrent.Future[Unit]).

```
def foo(myDB: DefaultDB): Future[Unit] = myDB.drop()
```

Comment: Thanks cchantep, I would also have been interrested in finding a way to run commands with ReactiveMongo.

Comment: That's an [advanced topic](http://reactivemongo.org/releases/0.11/documentation/advanced-topics/commands.html) that should only be considered if there is no operation in the existing API